# Why will WHERE statement not work in sqlQuery in RODBC?

Tags: r, rodbc, sybase-asa

We keep all our laboratory data in a Sybase database. When I want to do data manipulation and analysis I read the data into R with RODBC.

```
library(RODBC)
channellab <- odbcConnect("Labdata")
indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen')
```

So far so good, except that CGS.Specimen is a table for our entire lab holdings. There are almost 40000 specimens (rows) with 66 variables. It takes an unnecessary amount of time to read especially when I am only interested in the holdings of one study which has about 1000 specimens. The obvious way to fix it would be

```
indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode="RP"')
```

But when I run that I get

> [1] "42S22 -143 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Column not found: Column 'RP' not found" "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode=\"RP\"'"

I have played with quotation marks and I have played with escape slashes but alas I have gotten nowhere.

for instance

```
indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode= 'RP'  ')
```

Error: unexpected symbol in "indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode= 'RP"

```
indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,"SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode= 'RP'  ")
```

Error in .Call(C_RODBCFetchRows, attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), max, buffsize,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

What do you suggest?

Comment: Does the problem revolve around the single quotation marks around the sql statement getting messed up with the quotation marks around the variable value?

Comment: This error is due to the double quotes around RP.  I'm confused have you tried the single quotes in @Preet's answer?

Comment: Yes. I have tried Preet's suggestions. They do not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last error you report is from the .Call function to the c function RODBCFetchRows. Thus your problem with the quotation marks appears to be solved. However, with the said error you still have a problem. Perhaps the rows are not correctly reported (the c function tries to allocate vectors based on this value, but does not check for negative values). Try:

```
indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,"SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode= 'RP'", believeNRows = FALSE)
```

Comment: I tried running your line. No joy.  

> indivs
[1] "42000 -131 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Syntax error or access violation: near ',' in ...StudyCode= 'RP'[,] believeNRows =..."
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode= 'RP', believeNRows = FALSE'"                                
> str(indivs)
 chr [1:2] "42000 -131 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Anywhere]Syntax error or access violation: near ',' in ...StudyCode= 'RP'[,] b"| __truncated__ ...

Comment: Ooops, a little typo there ... the believeNRows = FALSE should not have been in the query string. Fixed it.

Comment: Mazal Tov! It works. Why do you think the number of rows returned by the ODBC connection is messed up. I guess it does not matter as long as we get it to work.

Comment: The manual talks of some Sybase drivers not reporting believable number of rows (same for some Oracle drivers and SQLight for Mac OS X). I don't know if the driver could be fixed (i.e. updated), but you might be able to increase performance by adjusting buffsize.

Answer (score 2):

Edited:

```
indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode=\'RP\'')
```

Ok can you run another query where some data is returned?

`WHERE StudyCode=StudyCode` for example? Does this give the same error about -ve lengths?

this means that the above is correct for escaping the StudyCode. The -Ve lenght  is another error. Can you return not all columns with * but specific columns where there are no nulls?

Comment: It did not work. I got Error: unexpected string constant in "indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode=''RP'"

Comment: It still does not work. Error in .Call(C_RODBCFetchRows, attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), max, buffsize,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed  
I do not have a clue what all that means but it does not work. What else can we try.

Comment: I tried indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT * from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode=StudyCode') and got Error in .Call(C_RODBCFetchRows, attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), max, buffsize,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Comment: I do not know if I understood your additional question, "Can you return not * specific columns where there are no nulls?" You may have meant that I run a line such as indivs <-sqlQuery(channellab,'SELECT SubjLastName, SubjSex, StudyCode from CGS.Specimen WHERE StudyCode=\'RP\''). I still got an error. Error in .Call(C_RODBCFetchRows, attr(channel, "handle_ptr"), max, buffsize,  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed

Comment: Some real time voip or im may be in order. Do you use gmail or skype? If so I am fjbuch on both.